# How to get value entered in stripe element input?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am new to Stripe element integration. Everything works fine but I'm having trouble with styling. Here is my code:

```
cardNumElement.on('focus', function(event) {
$('#card_num_label').addClass('active');
      if (event.empty) { //HERE GETTING EVENT.EMPTY UNDEFINED
         $('#card_num_label').removeClass('active');
     }
});
cardNumElement.on('blur', function(event) {
if (event.empty) {
         $('#card_num_label').removeClass('active');
     }
});
```

What I want to achieve is:

- Add active class selector to the label when user focuses on that element
- If the user enters a value, do not remove the active class selector
- If the user didn't enter a value and focus out from the element, remove the active class selector
  I can't detect whether user entered a value or not and I'm not getting a result event.

Answer (score 1):

`event.empty` isn't available on either the `focus` or `blur` events. The only valid property for those events is `event.elementType`.

If you want to get the status of the contents of the element, you'd use the `change` event instead: https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=cardElement#element_on_change-handler

Alternatively, you could use the private fields of the element, but bear in mind that these are subject to change at any time and are probably not reliable:

```
cardNumElement.on('focus', function(event) {
  $('#card_num_label').addClass('active');
  if (cardNumElement._implementation._empty) {
    $('#card_num_label').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```